# accumulate unexpected error with Drool

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I am trying to understand drools rule engine accumulate syntax but facing issue while trying to build it, this is my test `.drl` file

```
rule "Best Price"

    when
    $product : Product()
    accumulate( ProductDiscount(product == $product , $discount : discount);
       $avg : average($discount)
    )

    then
     //to do
end
```

With this Syntax , I am getting `accumulate unexpected` syntax and not sure what is the root cause for this as I was following the [official document.](http://docs.drools.org/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e9194)

I am using IDEA's Intelli and Drool6.4.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules seems to be pretty fine. The only problem I am wondering about, are your classes `Product` and `ProductDiscount` in the same package as your rule?

Comment: hmm, then it is really strange and hard to solve, do you think could you upload your whole project to github for example?

Comment: sure, I can do that, will be doing it today

Comment: here is the link for the code on github https://github.com/umeshawasthi/drool-sample/tree/master/src/main/java/com/drool/test/product.

Comment: I think that the problem is in your attribute 'discount' in the class 'ProductDiscount'. Your attribute 'discount' is a 'List'. But the 'average' function expects just single value.